# how to set ctrl+space for android studio in mac os?

Tags: macos, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

When I use Android Studio in the Windows operating system, I use the combination of control+space buttons to complete the code. This button combination ctrl+space does not work on Mac OS with normal keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in android studio from `File` menu > `Settings` item , opened below window:

[image: android studio ctrl+space on macos screenshot]

then select `Main Menu` > `Code Completion` > `Basic` item we can changing keyboard-shortcut for it.

You can replace any custom key combinations.